# How to check if a Specifc txt exist in a website and save link - python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have this website:https://geo1.ville.levis.qc.ca/grilleusage/default.aspx?zoneid=1
I need a code to check different **zoneid**, [1 to 3000]. and check if the word "H10" exists in that link (like this one https://geo1.ville.levis.qc.ca/grilleusage/default.aspx?zoneid=0160)
and if the word "H10" exits I want all the links that contain that word to be saved.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this example to iterate over different zones and check if there are links with `H10`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://geo1.ville.levis.qc.ca/grilleusage/default.aspx?zoneid={}"

for zoneid in range(159, 165):  # <--- adjust pages here, for eg. (1, 3001)
    u = url.format(zoneid)
    print("Checking {}".format(u))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(u).content, "html.parser")

    h10_links = soup.select('a:-soup-contains("H10")')
    for link in h10_links:
        print(link["href"])
```

Prints:

```
Checking https://geo1.ville.levis.qc.ca/grilleusage/default.aspx?zoneid=159
Checking https://geo1.ville.levis.qc.ca/grilleusage/default.aspx?zoneid=160
https://www.ville.levis.qc.ca/fileadmin/documents/pdf/permis/classes_usages_zonage_vdl.pdf
Checking https://geo1.ville.levis.qc.ca/grilleusage/default.aspx?zoneid=161
Checking https://geo1.ville.levis.qc.ca/grilleusage/default.aspx?zoneid=162
Checking https://geo1.ville.levis.qc.ca/grilleusage/default.aspx?zoneid=163
Checking https://geo1.ville.levis.qc.ca/grilleusage/default.aspx?zoneid=164
```

Comment: I'm trying to run the code but I keep getting this error message: NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.

Comment: @ouss26 You're using ancient version of `beautifulsoup`. Please upgrade the module.